# Insert data in separate linked lists depending on certain values?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to insert data in a separate linked list based on the value that has been given in the 'Gender' variable.

Please check below how it works with the current implementation and how I am attempting to make it look like.

I think there has to be a change in the `insertFirst()` and `printList()` function but I am not sure.

Example of how it works now is shown in the the input below:

```
Insert the code of the person Number 1: 1
Insert the age of the person Number 1: 1
Insert the gender of the person Number 1: 1
Insert the code of the person Number 2: 2
Insert the age of the person Number 2: 2
Insert the gender of the person Number 2: 0
Insert the code of the person Number 3: 3
Insert the age of the person Number 3: 3
Insert the gender of the person Number 3: 1

Code    Age     Gender
3       3       1
2       2       0
1       1       1
   Men
   Women
```

The expected result should be grouped by gender as follows:

```
MEN
 Code    Age     Gender                    
  3       3       1
  1       1       1

WOMEN
 Code    Age     Gender
  2       2       0
```

The code is displayed below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int N;

typedef struct people { /* a struct for people*/
    int code; /* a unique identifier for each person*/
    int age; 
    int gender; 
    struct people *next;
} ppl;

typedef ppl *pppl;        

ppl *head = NULL;
ppl *current = NULL;

//a function to insert nodes
void insertFirst(pppl *q, int code, int age, int gender)
{
    //create a link
    ppl *link = (ppl *)malloc(sizeof(ppl));
    
    link->code = code;
    link->age = age;
    link->gender = gender;
   
    //point it to old first node
    link->next = head;
    
    //point first to new first node
    head = link;
}


          
//display the list
void printList() {
    ppl *ptr = head;
    char myStrings[][23] = { "Code", "Age", "Gender" };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        printf("%s\t", myStrings + i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //start from the beginnings
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%d\t\%d\t\%d\n", ptr->code, ptr->age, ptr->gender);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }    
}

int main() {    
    pppl z1, z2;  
    int i, code1,  age1,  gender1; 

    z1 = NULL;
    z2 = NULL;

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        {
            printf("Insert the code of the person Number %d: ",i);
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &code1);         
        }
        printf("Insert the age of the person Number %d: ",i);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &age1);
        {
            printf("Insert the gender of the person Number %d: ",i);
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &gender1);
        }
    
        if (gender1 == 1)
            insertFirst(&z1,  code1,  age1,  gender1); // Here it stores in z1 for men
        else
            insertFirst(&z2, code1,  age1,  gender1); // Here it stores in z2 for women
    }
    //print list
    printList();

    printf("   Men \n");
    printList(z1); // I think if that function took parameters it would work like that for z1 and z2
    printf("   Women \n");
    printList(z2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove `head` and `current` and make them parameters of `insertFirst` and `printList`. For the former, at least `head` needs to be a reference parameter for changes to stick when it returns.

Comment: Dare I ask what the purpose of `q`, a pointer to pointer to `ppl` that is i'll-advisedly shrouding one level of indirection because you're hiding a pointer type in the alias `pppl`, is?? That you're not using it anywhere in that function speaks to a problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually, I have taken an example from a tutorial and I am attempting more complex stuff on it in order to learn more in depth the language. This part that you described was included in the initial part of the example itself.

Comment: Actually, that part I mentioned, and you included but have chosen not to use, is designed to allow list updates, including insertions, *without* needing a global `head` pointer. The looks like it *should* be building two lists (one for gender == 1, the other for anything else). It just never actually does so. Isn't your task really just about building an ordered linked list based on gender primarily (possibly code thereafter, but that isn't immediately obvious) ?

Comment: I think this is the case. You're right that this isn't utilized but if it is, it will make things easier. Can you please provide an answer with what you have in mind about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using your pointer-to list head parameter whatsoever. The very purpose of that argument it to allow updating a *specific* list. Since you're building two, that parameter should be used for the insertion; not some worthless global `head`. Printing would likewise involve those two arguments.

Sans a lot of error checking that should still be added, the idea is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct people
{             /* a struct for people*/
    int code; /* a unique identifier for each person*/
    int age;
    int gender;
    struct people *next;
} ppl;

/*
 * Creates a new ppl record, populating with the
 * provided arguments.
 */
ppl *make_ppl(int code, int age, int gender, ppl *next)
{
    ppl *p = malloc( sizeof *p );
    p->code = code;
    p->age = age;
    p->gender = gender;
    p->next = next;
    return p;
}

/*
 * insert a new node at the head of the provided list.
 * the new node becomes the new head via assignment
 * through the pointer-to-pointer to node.
 */
void insertFirst(ppl **ppHead, int code, int age, int gender)
{
    *ppHead = make_ppl(code, age, gender, *ppHead);
}


/*
 * Display the linked list with the provided preamble
 * title beforehand. note the 'head' pointer is by-value
 * and const, to ensure we do not modify the pointed-to
 * data. Further, we can use that pointer directly to
 * enumerate the list, with no ill effects to the caller.
 */
void printList(const char *title, const ppl *head)
{
    static const char *myStrings[] = {"Code", "Age", "Gender"};
    static const size_t n_strings = sizeof myStrings / sizeof *myStrings;

    puts(title);
    for (size_t i=0; i<n_strings; ++i)
        printf("\t%s", myStrings[i]);
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    // start from the beginning
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", head->code, head->age, head->gender);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

/*
 * Delete a linked list, starting at the head node
 * and following the link chain until exhaustion.
 * When done, the caller's pointer will be null and
 * the list is fully destroyed.
 */
void deleteList(ppl **ppHead)
{
    while (*ppHead)
    {
        ppl *p = *ppHead;
        *ppHead = p->next;
        free(p);
    }
}

int main()
{
    ppl *z1 = NULL;
    ppl *z2 = NULL;
    
    int code1, age1, gender1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert the code of the person Number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &code1);

        printf("Insert the age of the person Number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &age1);

        printf("Insert the gender of the person Number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &gender1);

        if (gender1 == 1)
            insertFirst(&z1, code1, age1, gender1); // Here it stores in z1 for men
        else
            insertFirst(&z2, code1, age1, gender1); // Here it stores in z2 for women
    }

    printList("Men", z1);
    printList("Women", z2);

    deleteList(&z1);
    deleteList(&z2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (based on your stated input)

```
Men
        Code    Age     Gender
        3       3       1
        1       1       1
Women
        Code    Age     Gender
        2       2       0
```

Also added was a node-creation function and a list cleanup.

Comment: What are the benefits of creating the `make_ppl`, the node creation function instead of not? Also, please add comments so it is easier to further analyze your solution.